# Python: modifying nested list elements using functions

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to extract contents from two separate pandas dataframes with the following code:

```
def get_content(df):
    content=[]
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        content.append(row.content)           
    return content

contents=[news,blog]
dfs=[news_df,blogs_df]
for df, content in zip(dfs,contents):
    content=get_content(df)
    print(len(content)) #  gives me correct values

print(len(blog),len(news)) # empty lists.
```

But rewriting the code gives me correct results:

```
def get_content(df):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        content.append(row.content)
    return content

news=[]
blog=[]
contents=[news,blog]
dfs=[news_df,blogs_df]
for df, content in zip(dfs,contents):
    content=get_content(df)
    print(len(content)) #  gives me correct values

print(len(blog),len(news)) # gives me correct results
```

I do not understand why the second code works but not the first.

Comment: What are `news`, `blog`? Can you supply a **[mcve]**? Otherwise, any answer will have to make assumptions.

Comment: @jpp: Thanks for asking. I missed initializing news and blog as empty lists, outside the get_content function. it works just fine now

Answer (score 0):

They are not changing because `df` and `content` are copies, not the original data (different locations in the memory).

Replace your for with this:

```
for index in range(len(contents)):
   contents[index] = get_content(dfs[index])
   print(len(contents[index]))  # gives me correct values
```

The reason it should work now, as opposed to your loop is because I am working on the values directly in the lists, rather than their copies.

Comment: Hi, if I set news and blog as empty lists, the values do get updated